# Escape any non-alphanumeric characters in a string using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like to escape non-alphanumeric characters occurring in a string as follows:

Say, the original string is: `"test_"`, I would like to transform as `"test\_"`.

In order to do this, one approach I can take by scanning the original string, and constructing a new string and while a non-alphanumeric character is found, append a `'\'` in front of this character.

But I am wondering if there is any cleaner approach to do the same using regular expression.

Comment: Check this: https://regex101.com/r/gdVh6r/1/codegen?language=java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the replaceable parameter as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "test_";
        s = s.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}]", "\\\\$0");

        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
test\_
```

**Notes:**

1. `$0` represents the string matched by the complete regex pattern, `[^\\p{Alnum}]`.
2. `\p{Alnum}` specifies alphanumeric character and `^` inside `[]` is used to negate the pattern. Learn more about patterns from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
3. Notice the extra pair of `\\` which is to escape `\` that has been used to escape `\`.